# CMD if statements not working as required

Tags: cmd

The code below is for a script running with Windows Deployment Services.

However I have this issue where after it runs the y and no actually don't, if I click Y or N it still does it anyways, can I please have some guidance to where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

```
@echo off
Title Deployment Services - First Run

    :start
set /p intelchipset =Would you like to install Intel Chipset [y/n] ?: 
if "%intelchipset%"=="y". goto intelyes
if "%intelchipset%"=="n". goto basicprograms
if "%intelchipset%"=="Y". goto intelyes
if "%intelchipset%"=="N". goto basicprograms

    :intelyes
TITLE Deployment Services - Installing Intel Chipset
ECHO Deployment Services: Installing Intel Chipset 
net use G: \\StoreWDS\FirstTimeSetup
G:\Intel.exe
net use G: /delete
ECHO Intel Chipset Installed
goto basicprograms

    :basicprograms
TITLE Deployment Services - Basic Programs
set /p basicapps =Would you like to install Basic Programs [y/n] ?: 
if "%basicapps%"=="y" goto basicprogramsyes
if "%basicapps%"=="n" goto end

    :basicprogramsyes
net use G: \\StoreWDS\FirstTimeSetup
G:\install.exe
net use G: /delete
ECHO Basic Applications Installed
goto end


    :end
TITLE Deployment Services - Finishing Up
ECHO Running Aero Theme
set /p osversion =Is this installing Windows 8 or 8.1 or newer [y/n] ?: 
if "%osversion%"=="y" goto OS8
if "%osversion%"=="n" goto OS7

    :OS8
rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"%windir%\Resources\Themes\aero.theme"
ECHO Aero Theme Applied
GOTO continueend

    :OS7
rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"%windir%\Resources\Themes\aero.theme"
ECHO Aero Theme Applied
GOTO continueend

    :continueend
Echo Running Permissions - Notepad will open
net use G: \\StoreWDS\FirstTimeSetup
runas /user:User cmd
G:\permissions.txt 
G:\AddWSUS
takeown /f %systemdrive%\ /r
winsat dwm
net use G: /delete
ECHO Everything has been finished
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
if /i "%intelchipset%"=="y" goto intelyes
if /i "%intelchipset%"=="n" goto basicprograms
goto start
```

`if /i` ignores case. `==` is fine for `exactly matches`- but the dot must be removed. The strings must EXECTLY match whether `==` or `equ` is used.

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto label` if none of the choices match - otherwise batch simply charges on through.

The same will be the case obviously for the OS test.

Note that `SET/P` leaves the variable unchanged should the user merely reply <kbd>Enter</kbd>.